# Random team generator

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a button that randomly selects an item from one array, and a button the randomly selects from a different array.

I want have a third button that would randomly select from the returns of the first two arrays.

Here is what I have:

```
//array 1
document.getElementById("east").addEventListener("click", getEast);

function getEast() {
    var x = [
        '1',
        '2',
    ];

    var rand = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];

    document.getElementById("east").innerHTML = rand;

}

//array 2
document.getElementById("west").addEventListener("click", getWest);

function getWest() {
    var y = [
        '3',
        '4',
    ];

    var rand = y[Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length)];

    document.getElementById("west").innerHTML = rand;
}

document.getElementById("champ").addEventListener("click", getChamp);

// select champ from the two conference winners
function getChamp() {
    var z = [
        "function myEast();",
        "function myWest();"
    ];

    var rand = z[Math.floor(Math.random() * z.length)];

    document.getElementById("champ").innerHTML = rand;
}
```

Comment: `"function myEast();",` ????

Comment: Create a new array with two regional winners and apply the same logic to select randomly one of its elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code to this

```
function getEast() {
    var x = [
        '1',
        '2',
    ];

    var rand = x[Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)];

    document.getElementById("east").innerHTML = rand;

    return rand;
}

function getWest() {
    var y = [
        '3',
        '4',
    ];

    var rand = y[Math.floor(Math.random() * y.length)];

    document.getElementById("west").innerHTML = rand;

    return rand;
}


// select champ from the two conference winners
function getChamp() {
    var z = [
        getEast, getWest
    ];

    var rand = z[Math.floor(Math.random() * z.length)]();

    document.getElementById("champ").innerHTML = rand;
}

document.getElementById("east").addEventListener("click", getEast);
document.getElementById("west").addEventListener("click", getWest);
document.getElementById("champ").addEventListener("click", getChamp);
```

Comment: that comes up undefined.

Comment: only the second array returns an item

Comment: @adam.cox what do you mean? Which array?

Comment: @adam.cox i have edited my answer and added the required event listeners at the bottom to make everything work properly

Comment: with your changes, the only function that returns a number is the second of the two arrays

Comment: @adam.cox, i noticed that and i have edited my answer, please try it again

Comment: awesome! it appears to working on my end.  thank you!